# react native getting a error as this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hi there i"m new to react native during my built process i am getting this error

`this.setState is not a function`

and my code

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

componentDidMount(){
 Proximity.addListener(this._proximityListener);
}
 _proximityListener(data) {
   this.setState({
     proximity: data.proximity,
     distance: data.distance // Android-only 
   });
 }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            00
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

how to solve this error ? .,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your _proximityListener function into an arrow function like this:

`_proximityListener = (data) => {...`

This will bind the method to the class and give that method access to the 'this' keyword. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `componentDidMount` function to

```
componentDidMount(){
  Proximity.addListener(this._proximityListener.bind(this));
}
```